# initialize an arry in the loop

Tags: c++, sorting

So, I'm a beginner in c++ and I want to compare the execution time of bubble sort using templates and classic function for small number of elements (N=2,4,6,8,10,12,16). Because the N is so small, I am looping the function for say 1000000 times to get measurable results. I do it this way:

```
main() { 

int t1, t2, h, m, s,k=0;
    int a[4] = {800,768,700,652};

t1=GetTickCount();

for (k=0; k<1000000; k++){
// bubble_sort_template<4>(a);
   bubble_sort_function(a,4);
}
t2=GetTickCount() - t1;
```

The results aren't as I expected, because as I run the loop for the second time, my array is already sorted. How do I initialize the array again before the loop stars?

Comment: Put the array inside the { and } of the loop?

Comment: Remember that when you put initialization inside the loop. You will need to take care to count sorting time separately from reinitialization time!

Answer (score 3):

Move the array definition inside the loop:

```
for (k=0; k<1000000; k++) {
  int a[4] = {800, 768, 700, 652};
  bubble_sort_function(a,4);
}
```

In this way, each time you execute the loop, you are using the original array.

In addition, two points you need to be aware of when you compare performance:

- it's not likely that the templated and non-templated versions will have different performance behaviors. During *compile time*, the compiler generates different functions according to the type parameter. So when you test the function, you're actually running the same code.
- When you compare performance of different algorithms, a small input (small array in this case) usually does not suffice since both run very fast. You'd better try larger inputs to magnify the difference between the algorithms.

This should explain why you get similar results for different versions.

Comment: Well, this is my homework assignment and we were told that for small input sizes, the template algorithm should be about 4-5 times faster.
This was my idea to examine it. Can you think of another way to prove it? It doesn't have to be done by a program.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
main() { 

int t1, t2, h, m, s,k=0;


t1=GetTickCount();

for (k=0; k<1000000; k++){
  int a[4] = {800,768,700,652};
// bubble_sort_template<4>(a);
   bubble_sort_function(a,4);
}
t2=GetTickCount() - t1;
```

Comment: thats exactly what @yang said. You could just have upvoted his answer if yours is the same.

Comment: @IcyFlame: Downvoting someone (especially a new user) for being a few seconds slower than someone else with a similar answer is rather harsh. It's not a race.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: All I can say is that, When I did the same thing I got downoted... So well I guessed thats how it worked! And he need not answer the same thing again and again... it does not add any value..

Comment: @IcyFlame: You can vote how you like, of course; but the usual etiquette is to upvote good answers and downvote bad (i.e. misleading or wrong) answers - preferably with an explanation. Requiring everyone to double-check that no-one else has written a similar answer before posting would tend to discourage people from bothering to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just move the initialisation statement into the body of the loop?  The following compiles just fine for me (as C++):

```
extern void bubble_sort_function(int *, int);

main()
{
    for (int k=0; k<1000000; k++){
        int a[4] = {800,768,700,652};
        bubble_sort_function(a,4);
   }
}
```